# Angular 7 - Changing sidebar and element z-index

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

I want to change the z-index of sidebar in my Angular 7 web app. The sidebar is created with ng-sidebar and its default z-index is 9999999, as seen in the picture below. On my sidebar I have jqwidget dropdownboxes which have a[image] default z-index 2000. 
After reading multiple SO and forums posts with similar problems as well as trying with *Inspect Element*, the problem seems to be that when I click on the dropdownbox, the values are hidden behind the sidebar because of the lower z-index. I can't seem to override the z-index of the sidebar or the dropdownbox element in order to make it be seen.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override css in css file related with your component.

```
.ng-sidebar {
     z-index: 1
}
```

If this doesn't work, increase specificity of your selector.